# Do you guys normally create a new .dart file for the next screen or stick the coding to the same page?

Tags: flutter, dart

i am new to coding, do you guys create a new dart file for the next screen?

currently i have a homepage with have a start button , do i create a new .dart like a settingpage.dart or continue on homepage?

please advise , thanks.

If i create a new .dart file , what are the code i need to include ?

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onLongPress: () => // Navigate,
  child: const Image(
    height: 110,
    width: 110,
    image: AssetImage("lib/images/start-png.png"),
  ),
)
```

Comment: I would say that usually every class is a separate file, with the exception of `StatefulWidget`, where you also put its `State` class in the same file

Comment: you could tried to learn a stateManagement like BLOC or GETX

Answer (score 0):

To navigate to a new page, `route` is used in `flutter`. You can create `Material App or Cupertino App` with `Stateless Widget` and `Stateful Widget`. You can create multiple `class` in one `dart` file. However, it is more efficient to manage the code by dividing it into separate `dart` files.

There is no right answer, but learn about `design-pattern` and use the method that is appropriate for your project!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make a new class in the same Dart file, but the problem with this approach is that it is fine until you are having three or four classes in your whole project (i.e. you're creating single page or two page applications). Any bigger than that and you need to create various .dart files to be able to manage all the code so that you can distinguish any errors quickly.
Also it makes easier for any other person to understand your code, I'll give you a few good articles on how to write code, what are the best code practices you can follow.

1. https://simonauer.medium.com/best-practices-basic-tips-on-writing-good-flutter-code-dd05d56bf27c
2. https://codewithandrea.com/videos/top-dart-tips-and-tricks-for-flutter-devs/

Also if you are creating a new .dart file you need to add two things before you'll be able to use that file :

1. `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`
2. `stful` or `stless` depending on whether you need a stateful or a stateless class.

which is going to look like this when all put together:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ClassName extends StatefulWidget {
  const ClassName({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ClassName> createState() => _ClassNameState();
}

class _ClassNameState extends State<ClassName> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , i had added those on my new page but , i am having problem to navigate to a new dart file , i have added my code above , what should i write to let the button to navigate to the next dart file

Comment: lets say you made a stateful widget with name `SecondScreen` and you're navigating from `FirstScreen`. In the first screen add the following code:


`onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondScreen()));`

Comment: oh thanks , i manage to solve it , turn out my No application found for TargetPlatform.android_x86. the emulator freezed.